# Column 'ITEM_DETAILS.VENDOR_NAME' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am working on Inventory system project and i need to ask one thing in which got stuck kindly show me how to get rid of this issue, I am writing an sql query as follows:

```
Select 
ITEM_DETAILS.VENDOR_NAME,
LEDGER.VENDOR_NAME, 
ITEM_DETAILS.AMOUNT,
LEDGER.CREDIT,
(Sum(ITEM_DETAILS.AMOUNT)-LEDGER.CREDIT) 
as Balance From ITEM_DETAILS 
inner join LEDGER on ITEM_DETAILS.VENDOR_NAME=LEDGER.VENDOR_NAME
where LEDGER.VENDOR_NAME='memon'
Group by ITEM_DETAILS.VENDOR_NAME
```

But when i am trying to run this it gives me following error:

```
Column 'ITEM_DETAILS.VENDOR_NAME' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Any help would be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

You need To add Columns (Other Than Aggregation Function) while using aggregation Function

```
Select 
ITEM_DETAILS.VENDOR_NAME,
LEDGER.VENDOR_NAME, 
ITEM_DETAILS.AMOUNT,
LEDGER.CREDIT,
(Sum(ITEM_DETAILS.AMOUNT)-LEDGER.CREDIT) 
as Balance From ITEM_DETAILS 
inner join LEDGER on ITEM_DETAILS.VENDOR_NAME=LEDGER.VENDOR_NAME
where LEDGER.VENDOR_NAME='memon'
Group by ITEM_DETAILS.VENDOR_NAME,
LEDGER.VENDOR_NAME, 
ITEM_DETAILS.AMOUNT,
LEDGER.CREDIT,
```